# Get conversations in a database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
ofmessagearchive (fromID, toID, message, sentDate)
```

I need to get the last 10 messages of each conversation of a determine user.

Example:
UserA have two friends (UserB and UserC)

I need to get the last 10 messages of conversation with UserB, and the last 10 messages of conversation with UserC.

Comment: I have no ideia how do this. I started well:SELECT 
 body as mensagem, 
 sentDate 
FROM (
 SELECT * FROM ofmessagearchive 
  WHERE fromJID = ? OR toJID = ? 
  ORDER BY sentDate DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 10
)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can't get that in SQL without functions.

You can get all it using function or java function using this plan

1) Get all users for user A

```
  select distinct id from 
   (Select distinct toid as id from ofmessagearchive where fromID=UserA union
   ( select distinct fromid as id from ofmessagearchive where toID=UserA) ) as ids;
```

2) Go via every id from that list, and select last 10 messages/print it.